# Get value of textview after Inflating in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-inflate

I am inflating the `passenger_details_layout` in `main_passenger_details_layout`.At run time i am setting the values in TextView .  I am setting up `pax_id` that is invisible for every row that i am inflating in it.So on click of passenger_details_layout i want to call a new activity and pass the `pax_id` to the new activity.
`Pax_id` will be like 1,2,3 for every time for loop will run.So on click of 1 row i want to get the `pax_id` of first row that i have set.

Please help how could i do this Will be thank full to you.

**Code to Infalate**

```
ItinResponse data = obj.parseXMLData(fXmlFile);
        List<SectorRecords> sectorList = data.getSectorRecordsDetails();
        int items = 0;
        List<PassengerDetails> listdata = data.getPaxDetails();
        int i = 0;
        for (PassengerDetails elements : listdata) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.passenger_details_layout, main, false);
            firstName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.first_pax_name);
            pax_id = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.pax_id);
            firstName.setText(elements.getFirstName() + " "
                    + elements.getLastName());
            pax_id.setText(elements.getPaxId());
            main.addView(layout, i);
            i++;


 layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)"+pax_id.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
```

On every row is showing the last pax id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do nothing what you are trying

Replace this

```
pax_id.setText(elements.getPaxId());
```

to

```
layout.setId(Integer.parseInt(elements.getPaxId()));
```

And in your Layout Click

```
layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)"+layout.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
```

Every time you will get the Unique ID that u want to set

All the best...!!!!

Comment: try if u have any doubt let me know

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
TextView paxView = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pax_id);
String pax_value = paxView.getText().toString();
```

Comment: layout is always giving me the last pax id that i have set in that

Comment: @PoojaDubey you are using setText which will replace the old with the new one so you get the last text set to textview

Comment: so how can i do this so that for every row i have a unique id

Comment: for every pax i am geeting PaxId i have to set that and pass that in the new activity

Comment: @PoojaDubey It seems you want to make a list of `PassengerDetails`, Why don't you try a `ListView`for that. You will get much better control in ListView.

Comment: also there is no need to initialize views everytime in for loop. initialize once and use the same

Comment: i don't have to use a listview

Comment: What you can try is v.getTag() and parse it to `PassengerDetails`.

Comment: @GauravGupta how can we do this please help i am new in android

Comment: PassengerDetails details = (PassengerDetails) v.getTag();          String text = details.getPaxId();

Comment: your not getting my question

Comment: where i will do this what u said @GauravGupta

Comment: @PoojaDubey I think i am suggesting something that Dynamo has already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

On button click of every row do like this

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,YOUR_NEXT_ACTIVIY.class);
                intent.putExtra("paxid",  pax_id.getText());
                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ItinResponse data = obj.parseXMLData(fXmlFile);
        List<SectorRecords> sectorList = data.getSectorRecordsDetails();
        int items = 0;
        List<PassengerDetails> listdata = data.getPaxDetails();
        int i = 0;
        for (PassengerDetails elements : listdata) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.passenger_details_layout, main, false);
            firstName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.first_pax_name);
            pax_id = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.pax_id);
            firstName.setText(elements.getFirstName() + " "
                    + elements.getLastName());
            pax_id.setText(elements.getPaxId());
            layout.setTag(elements.getPaxId());
            main.addView(layout, i);
            i++;
layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String paxId = v.getTag().toString();
                        // do some staff
                    }
                });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
        ItinResponse data = obj.parseXMLData(fXmlFile);
        List<SectorRecords> sectorList = data.getSectorRecordsDetails();
        int items = 0;
        List<PassengerDetails> listdata = data.getPaxDetails();
        int i = 0;
        for (PassengerDetails elements : listdata) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.passenger_details_layout, main, false);
            firstName = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.first_pax_name);
            pax_id = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.pax_id);
            firstName.setText(elements.getFirstName() + " "
                    + elements.getLastName());
            pax_id.setText(elements.getPaxId());
            layout.setTag(elements);
            main.addView(layout, i);
            i++;


            layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    PassengerDetails elements = (PassengerDetails) v.getTag();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)"+elements.getPaxId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
        }
```